Makefile for 2 targets with different prerequisites but with single command to generate both
With 2 targets each having a specific prerequisite and a single command to build them we can use this makefile
a.target: a.req
    build_a_and_b

b.target: b.req
    build_a_and_b

But if the 2 targets require to be built the command will be run twice.
I found that in recent make it exists grouped targets that takes into account commands generating multiple targets:
a.target b.target &: a.src b.src
    build_a_and_b

This solves the above issue but introduce a new anomaly: if no target is obsolete but a.src is newer than b.target the command is run when it should not as b.target depends only on b.src.
Of course same error exists also when switching a and b roles.
How would it be possible to execute only once the command when a target is older than its own source only?

By the way I realize that my question is wrong. The first list of rules is doing what I need when the command update actually the target file. I have been abused by testing with --dry-run modifier to check what would happen without doing anything.

The command is called build_a_and_b, so I would expect that both a.target and b.target are rebuilt if either a.src or b.src have changed. If that is not the case, then I don't get what build_a_and_b is doing.

@ssbssa: What make you think that build_a_and_build_b would not do what it says? It is because it does both jobs that I don't want it to be called twice when both jobs are due. But when using make -n (which do not actually call the command, and therefore cannot guess what the command does), then make indicates it will call twice the command if a and b need to be rebuilt.

It seems to me that build_a_and_b is NOT doing what it says, since it apparently only updates a.target if a.src changes, but the name implies that both a.target and b.target will be rebuilt.

Unfortunately there's no way to do this with grouped targets.  For a grouped target all the prerequisites are combined for both targets, regardless of how you define them.
If you don't care about parallel builds you can simply define two rules and the first one that runs will update the other one, then make will see that the second one is already updated and won't run the recipe again.
If you want to have parallel builds then it's not really possible, because the only way make can know to not build both at the same time is if they are linked together and when link them together you get this result.  At least, I can't think of a way to avoid it.
